# Check query count and perform action in PostgreSql function

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I've below function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.view_function()
 RETURNS TABLE (
    uid VARCHAR,
    namingid VARCHAR,
    service VARCHAR,
    servicetype VARCHAR,
    name VARCHAR,
    location VARCHAR )

 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare

    count     Integer;

begin

    RETURN QUERY 
  SELECT DISTINCT etm.uid,
  etm.namingid,
  etm.service,
  etm.servicetype,
  el.name,
  el.location
  FROM public.table1 etm
   LEFT JOIN public.table2 bt ON etm.namingid = bt.businessid
   LEFT JOIN public.table3 at2 ON etm.namingid = at2.aliasid
   LEFT JOIN table4 el ON etm.uid::text = el.uid::text AND etm.namingid::text = el.name::text;

END; $function$
;
```

I want to upload query's result in aws bucket. But before doing that I need to know the count and then export the data of query output, if count is greater than zero.

I want to call this `aws_s3.query_export_to_s3` in function, only if query's output is greater than zero. We need to use query as param in `aws_s3.query_export_to_s3` method too, but how can I avoid it running twice, to check count and then to get query output. Wanted to do it in single execution only.

Like, run query, store output data in some `tmp` variable, check count of that variable, if its grate than zero, then export that `tmp` variable. Something like that..

Not able to find a way. Can anyone suggest ?

Update

This a trigger which is set on `mainTable`, and fills every time `table4` table whenever there are new inserts. And I'm using `table4` in query in above function

```
create trigger my_tigger after
insert
  on
  public.mainTable referencing new table as table4 for each statement execute function view_function()
```

Comment: You can `create temp table tmp_output on commit drop as select...`, then [check the `rowcount`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) and if it's non-zero, `select aws_s3.query_export_to_s3('select * from tmp_output;');`. If you also wish for this function to return the contents you're exporting to the caller, you can finish with `return query select * from tmp_output;`

Comment: About the edit: I doubt that trigger is set on your table because for that to work, a `view_function()` would have to have `returns trigger` in its signature and yours `returns table` instead. This would give you the `ERROR:  function view_function must return type trigger`: see [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ouHT24p3). If that's a result of you obfuscating/anonymising your code, it might be a good idea to not re-use names like that.

Comment: @Zegarek, yes correct, but can you please suggest how can I use table4 as per my trigger, in your code you have shared ?

Comment: I've added an example at the end. Is that what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

PL/pgSQL exposes a [`ROW_COUNT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) system status indicator. You can save the output of your function into a temp table and `if ROW_COUNT>0 then` and only then do the export. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/rzP66sw0)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.view_function()
 RETURNS TABLE (
    uid         TEXT,
    namingid    TEXT,
    service     TEXT,
    servicetype TEXT,
    name        TEXT,
    location    TEXT)
LANGUAGE sql AS $function$
SELECT DISTINCT etm.uid,
  etm.namingid,
  etm.service,
  etm.servicetype,
  el.name,
  el.location
FROM         public.table1 etm
   LEFT JOIN public.table2 bt  ON etm.namingid = bt.businessid
   LEFT JOIN public.table3 at2 ON etm.namingid = at2.aliasid
   LEFT JOIN table4 el         ON  etm.uid::text = el.uid::text 
                              AND etm.namingid::text = el.name::text 
$function$;
```

```sql
create procedure public.export_not_empty_view_function_output_to_s3() 
language plpgsql as $p2$
declare v_rowcount int;
begin
  create temp table tmp_output on commit drop 
    as select * from public.view_function();
  GET DIAGNOSTICS v_rowcount=ROW_COUNT;
  if v_rowcount>0 then
    perform aws_s3.query_export_to_s3('select * from tmp_output;');
  end if;
  drop table tmp_output;
end $p2$;
```

You could also make this a function and pass along the status you'd normally get on output from [`aws_s3.query_export_to_s3()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html#aws_s3.export_query_to_s3-output-parameters), or a bunch of `null` or `0`, or no rows at all if it ends up not attempting the export.

```sql
create function public.export_not_empty_view_function_output_to_s3() 
returns table (rows_uploaded  bigint,
               files_uploaded bigint,
               bytes_uploaded bigint) language plpgsql as $p2$
declare v_rowcount int;
begin
  create temp table tmp_output on commit drop 
    as select * from public.view_function();
  GET DIAGNOSTICS v_rowcount=ROW_COUNT;
  if v_rowcount>0 then
    return query select * 
    from aws_s3.query_export_to_s3('select * from tmp_output;');
  else 
    return query select null,null,null;
  --return query select 0,0,0;
  --return query select 0,0,0 limit 0; --no rows
  end if;
  drop table tmp_output;
end $p2$;
```

---

If you want this to take place in a [statement-level trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html), your function should be defined with `returns trigger` and finish by `return null`. [Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/GxSAi4hE)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.view_function()
 RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $function$
declare rc int;
begin
  drop table if exists tmp_view_function_output;
  create temp table tmp_view_function_output on commit drop as 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
      etm.uid,
      etm.namingid,
      etm.service,
      etm.servicetype,
      el.name,
      el.location
    FROM         public.table1 etm
       LEFT JOIN public.table2 bt  ON etm.namingid = bt.businessid
       LEFT JOIN public.table3 at2 ON etm.namingid = at2.aliasid
       LEFT JOIN table4 el         ON  etm.uid::text = el.uid::text 
                                  AND etm.namingid::text = el.name::text;
  GET DIAGNOSTICS rc = ROW_COUNT;
  if rc>0 then
    perform aws_s3.query_export_to_s3('select * from tmp_view_function_output');
  end if;
  drop table tmp_view_function_output;
  return null;
end $function$;

create trigger my_tigger after insert on public.mainTable 
   referencing new table as table4 
   for each statement execute function public.view_function();
```

And again, it would be a good idea to save the output of the `query_export_to_s3()` function to a table somewhere, or broadcast it through [`pg_notify()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html); otherwise [`PERFORM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-GENERAL-SQL) discards them.
Also, if that's how you actually set up the `left join`s, it will always have non-zero `row_count` as long as there's something in `table1`.

Comment: public.view_function() will be called on one trigger which is created on table, but how export_not_empty_view_function_output_to_s3 will be called ?

Comment: `public.view_function()` is called inside it, so if you set things up like above, your trigger should now instead call `export_not_empty_view_function_output_to_s3`. If you want, you can build all that logic from `export_not_empty_view_function_output_to_s3` into your `public.view_function()` instead. The question you posted doesn't mention any wider context in which you attempt any of these operations - if it makes things problematic, it might be worth adding a few details on that part of things.

Comment: please check my update in question, How can I set up now according to your answer ?